# Get current Sort Key Of Backgrid Table

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I have following table made by Backgrid.js:

```
this.grid = new FixedWidthGrid({
        columns: this.columns,
        row: SelectableDocumentContextMenuRow.extend({
            contextMenu: ContextMenuHelper.onRightClick
        }),
        collection: self.collection,
        header: FilterHeader,
        contextMenu: ContextMenuHelper.onRightClick
    });
```

Now, when I click on a header label, the entire table gets sorted by that attribute on the client.

How can I get the current sort key/attribute (e.g. name, age etc.) of the collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using backbone.paginator you should be able to get this by checking the value of `collection.state.sortKey`